# updating column when not present in other table [large data set]

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization

I have two tables `entries` and `users` that has following columns

```sql
create table entries
(
    id      int(11) unsigned auto_increment primary key,
    user_id int unsigned null,
    status  enum ('active', 'inactive', 'blocked')
) 
create index user_id on entries (user_id);

------------------------

create table users
(
    id    int(11) unsigned auto_increment primary key,
    email varchar(255) not null,
    name  varchar(255) not null,
    phone varchar(255) not null
)
```

There are 5 million records in `users` table and around 20 million records in `entries` table and a lot of them have dangling `user_id` values, meaning `user_id` is pointing to a non-existant value in `users` table.

I'd like to update those values in `entries` as efficiently as possible without locking the entire table for an update for many minutes.

I've tried using batch updates by providing different status each time i.e.

```sql
UPDATE entries
SET user_id = null
WHERE user_id IS NOT NULL
  AND status = 'active'
  AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT id
                 FROM users
                 WHERE id = entries.user_id);
```

but had to kill query after a couple of minutes. any suggestions?

Comment: Can a user have more than one status? Sounds odd, so I had to ask

Comment: @RiggsFolly users don't have status, only entries and they can have only one status

Comment: Excuse my terminology mistake. It looks like you are creating orphans with this query. Is that how you ended up with so many entries compared to users

Comment: yes, unfortunatelly this is a legacy system and we have to work with what we have...

Comment: Would it not be of benefit in the long run to remove these orphans from entries

Comment: it would, but this is not what this question is about. plus in the current application logic entries can live without users and the other way around

Comment: And you are happy to continue the mess?

Answer (score 0):

You might find that adding an index to the `entries` table speeds up the update:

```sql
CREATE INDEX idx ON entries (user_id, status);
```

Comment: I dropped a lot of info from the definiton but there is an index already. i'll udpate my question